# Can we add the same remote site settings to two packages with the same namespace?

Tags: 2gp, 2gmp

Is this possible to include the same remote site settings to two packages with the same namespace?

I mean, won't this break the installation of these two package into the same org?

Answer (score 2):

We can't have two Remote Site Settings with the same name in two packages with the same namespace, but we can have the same URL under different names in two packages

Comment: I *believe* this constraint is only relevant if you try to install both on the same org, where you get an error, rather than at the time a package version is created. I think this rule (unique names) applies to all metadata if you want co-installation. Let me know if I am wrong in this belief.

Comment: yes, I mentioned this in question